# Simplify $(p)(\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n) + (1-p)(-\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n)$ to $\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^{n+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The expression was simplified in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384592/finding-markov-chain-transition-matrix-using-mathematical-induction). I'm trying to simplify it but I got stuck. Multiplying all the factors and regrouping didn't work, but maybe I'm doing the wrong regrouping.

Also, I don't understand why the $(2p-1)^n$ dropped the exponent in the second line of the same solution.

Comment: You are probably having a minus sign problem. Makes you a member of my club.

Comment: The answers show me I indeed had that problem. I kinda feel bad for making this question.

Comment: Why feel bad? You asked, now you know. Success.

Comment: Um, I guess you're right. Now I know I have to be more careful with signs. I was cancelling out both $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take $\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n$ common and simplify.

$(p)(\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n) + (1-p)(-\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n)$

Taking $\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n$ common, we have

$\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n\left(p-(1-p)\right)$

$\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n\left(2p-1\right)$

$\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^{n+1}$

Answer (score 4):

$$p\cdot (1/2)(2p-1)^n +(1-p) \cdot (-1/2)(2p-1)^n = \\
p \cdot (1/2)(2p-1)^n +(p-1) \cdot(1/2)(2p-1)^{\color{red}{n}}= \\ \left[\frac{p}{2}+\frac{p}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right](2p-1)^n =\\ (2p-1)\cdot(1/2) (2p-1)^n$$

You are correct that an $n$ was missing; I inserted an extra line which should help clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll accept Maazul's (since he answered first). I already upvoted yours.

Answer (score 4):

Start with: $(p)(\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n) + (1-p)(-\frac{1}{2}(2p-1)^n) = x$
 (I'm setting it equal to $x$ so it's easier to follow.)

$\therefore (p)(2p-1)^{n} + (1-p)(-1)(2p-1)^{n} = 2x$
Factor the $(2p-1)^{n}$:
$\therefore (2p-1)^{n} \cdot (p + (1-p)(-1)) = 2x$
$\therefore (2p-1)^{n} \cdot (p + (p-1)) = 2x$
$\therefore (2p-1)^{n} \cdot (2p-1) = 2x$
By law of exponent addition:
$(2p-1)^{n} \cdot (2p-1)^{1} = 2x$
$(2p-1)^{n+1} = 2x$
$\therefore \frac{1}{2} \cdot (2p-1)^{n+1} = x$

And there we are at the solution!
$ = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (2p-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: Your answer is very detailed too, and I feel embarrassed for missing that $(-1)$. Have an upvote.

Comment: Don't feel embarrassed! Learning is good. :-)